# How to reorder column of rdlc report on runtime, winforms

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I want to reorder and hide the column of rdlc column on runtime...any body have any idea...

I have an idea bind rdlc without .xsd(dataset designer) but with datatable and reorder the datatable on runtime and bind again the reordered datatable with rdlc. but rdlc report cannot bind with out .xsd(dataset desginer)